# SonarQube Scanner - SocketException Socket Closed - Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to scan my project with sonarqube and no matter what I try, it fails when trying to upload the report to the local sonarqube server.

When scanning as a maven goal *or* using the sonar-scanner download, it reports the same type of issue:

**sonar-scanner**

```
10:28:42.304 DEBUG: Upload report
10:28:52.553 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:28:52.554 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
10:28:52.557 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:28:52.558 INFO: Total time: 28.827s
10:28:52.775 INFO: Final Memory: 49M/298M
10:28:52.776 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:28:52.777 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=abc:abc
...
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
...
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

**Maven sonar:sonar goal**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.193 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-31T10:38:54-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 80M/452M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project abc: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=abc:abc&projectName=abc: timeout: Socket closed -> [Help 1]
```

Looking into the sonar server's logs, I found the following relevant looking statement in access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2018:10:39:04 -0500] "POST /api/ce/submit?projectKey=abc:abc&projectName=abc HTTP/1.1" 400 56 "-" "ScannerMaven/3.3.0.603/3.5.0" "AWFM1VQ1EuWVn5rHAAAf"
```

And this error in the web.log

```
2018.01.31 10:39:04 WARN  web[AWFM1VQ1EuWVn5rHAAAf][o.s.s.w.ServletRequest] Can't read file part for parameter report
java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket    
...
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
```

I've tried using the following versions with the same results:

```
| sonar-scanner | maven sonar plugin | sonarqube |
| n/a           | 3.4.0.905          | 6.5       |
| n/a           | 3.4.0.905          | 6.7.1     |
| n/a           | 3.3.0.603          | 6.7.1     |
| 3.0.3.778     | n/a                | 6.7.1     |
```

I've also tried other projects of mine and they do the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**  I tried yet another project of mine, a tiny one, and it worked fine.  It seems that as long as the report upload takes less than 10 seconds it works.  However as soon as upload takes about 10 seconds, it gets cut off:

```
14:10:38.537 INFO: Analysis report generated in abc\.scannerwork\scanner-report
14:10:38.537 DEBUG: Upload report
14:10:48.864 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:10:48.864 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
```

The difference in timestamps seems to always be 10s +/- a few hundred milliseconds.

I don't know why it's taking so long to upload such a small report when both items are on my same machine however is there a way to increase this timeout?

Comment: Did you check that the user that is executing the scan has [Execute Analysis rights](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) (Global Permissions)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier See my edit.  I don't think it's permissions.  Seems to be a timeout and the scanner for some reason takes forever to send the report to my local sonarqube instance.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters). Try using sonar.ws.timeout. The default setting is 60 seconds.So i am not sure this solves your issue. Out of the box on one machine the default values should work. Also try using localhost v.s. 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I tried setting `-Dsonar.ws.timeout=1000` and I also tried `-Dsonar.ws.timeout=1` but it seemed to have no effect either way.  Both failed with a _socket closed_ exception after 10s.  I also tried `-Dsonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000` but it too failed with the same error.